# alternating between high values and low values

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to generate $y(x)$ such that 
$x=1$ to $100$
$y(x)=1,2,3,10,20,30,7,8,9,70,80,90,10,11,12$

the idea is to come up with an equation where $y(x)$ alternate between high values and low values.... does anyone know of such a series of equation ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> $$
> y(x)=5.5x+(-1)^x(4.5x)
> $$

which generates the sequence:

> $$
> (1,20,3,40,5,60,7,80,9,100,...)
> $$

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks for answering this I am looking for a sequence like (1,2,3,10,20,30,7,8,9,70,80,90,10,11,12)